# Solution of nonlinear BVP is symmetric where derivative is 0

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, boundary-value-problem

For the following nonlinear BVP, $y''(x)+y(x)^2=0, y(0)=y(1)=0$, I wish to show that if $y'(x_0)=0$, then $y(x)=y(x_0-x)$. That is, the solution is symmetric about this point.

I've already shown that the nontrivial solution is unique, so it should be enough to show that $z(x)=y(x_0-x)$ satisfies the BVP where $y$ is a nontrivial solution but I can't seem to do this.

Comment: For that you just have to show that both $y(x)$, $z(x)$ are solutions to the same IVP with initial conditions in $x_0$. The discussion of the original boundary conditions comes after that.

Comment: @LutzLehmann Can you elaborate a little? I'm not seeing what you mean.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You make a little error, the reflection of $x$ at $x_0$ has the formula $\tau(x)=2x_0-x$. Then at the reflection point you have $\tau(x_0)=x_0$, so it is indeed a fixed point of the reflection.

You have now a point $x_0$, $y_0=y(x_0)$ and $y'(x_0)=0$. Next you consider with the corrected reflection $z(x)=y(2x_0-x)$ and get likewise $z(x_0)=y(x_0)=y_0$ and $z'(x_0)=-y'(x_0)=0$. Additionally $z$ is a solution of the DE. By uniqueness $z=y$ follows.

To progress further you probably have to use next that any solution is concave, so has at most two roots.

Comment: When you say $z$ is a solution to the DE, do you mean the BVP in the original post, or some other differential equation?

Comment: At first just tje differential equation with the described initial conditions. The conclusions for the BVP would be the next step.

Comment: Oh, okay, so I would need to show that $z(x)=y(2x_0-x)$ has two roots at $0$ and $1$ still?

Comment: If $y$ is a BVp solution, then as $z$ is the same function, it is the same BVP solution.

Comment: Oh, I see of course. One other question: why was it wrong to consider $z(x)=y(x_0-x)$ in the first place? Why do we need the 2?

Comment: What is $z(x_0)$ in that case?

Comment: In that case $z(x_0)=y(0)=0$?

Comment: And what has that to do with symmetry in $x_0$, or $y'(x_0)=0$? The factor $2$ results, as in any reflection, from the construction of the reflection as $x_0-(x-x_0)$.

Comment: Ah, I see! The function need not be reflective if that were the case, the reflection results from the construction you gave. Thank you.